# Calling C function from Kotlin using JNI

Tags: c, kotlin, java-native-interface, swig

I have created two C functions with the following declarations:

```
/* Function Declarations */
extern void compute_feature_set(double input[1102], double F_data[],
                                int F_size[2], double D_data[],
                                int D_size[3], double De_data[],
                                int De_size[4],
                                double V[7], double *mp,
                                double r[12], double *fM);
```

and...

```
/* Function Declarations */
extern void compute_feature_set_terminate(void);
```

I have added the code to a Cpp folder and created a CMakeList. The code compiles successfully however I am struggling to call the function using JNI in Kotlin.

How do I go about changing the functions to make them available for calling in Kotlin?

Also, I tried using SWIG:

The following commands return no errors:

```
swig -java compute_feature_set.i   
gcc -c compute_feature_set.c compute_feature_set_wrap.c -I/Users/ferasalsaab/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/include -I/Users/ferasalsaab/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18.0.1.1/Contents/Home/include/darwin
```

The last one outputs the following error:

COMMAND:

```
g++ -shared compute_feature_set.o compute_feature_set_wrap.o -o libcompute_feature_set.so
```

ERROR:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Comment: I am not sure there is enough information here to know how to help.   It is unclear what _"I am struggling to call the function using JNI in Kotlin"_ means.  What would be your first questions if someone asked you this same question?  (certainly you have read up on the topic?  [example](https://proandroiddev.com/android-ndk-interaction-of-kotlin-and-c-c-5e19e35bac74))

Comment: Use SWIG to generate JNI wrapper code. Be happy.

Comment: Basically, i do not know what the syntax is for the C functions are if I want to call them from Kotlin.

I initially wanted to just try compute_feature_set() but this does not work obviously. The more I read the more I think I need to change the syntax for the function declarations in the C Code to make this possible but I am unsure how to do this so they can be called? Does this clarify things?

Comment: If you want a concrete answer you will have to tell us something about each parameter: is it purely input, is it purely output, or is it a mix of the two? What does the function do with the `mp` and `fM` parameters? Is the caller supposed to pre-allocate an array of some size?

Answer (score 1):

I changed your function signature to take `double[]` arguments:

```
extern void compute_feature_set(double input[], double F_data[],
                                int F_size[], double D_data[],
                                int D_size[], double De_data[],
                                int De_size[],
                                double V[], double mp[],
                                double r[], double fM[]);
extern void compute_feature_set_terminate(void);
```

I created a `feature_set.i` with:

```
%module test
%include "arrays_java.i"
#include "include/feature_set.h"
```

And invoked SWIG as:

```
swig -c++ -java -includeall -package com.example.ferasas feature_set.i
```

Which resulted in the following Java class:

```
package com.example.ferasas;

public class test {
  public static void compute_feature_set(double[] input, double[] F_data, int[] F_size, double[] D_data, int[] D_size, double[] De_data, int[] De_size, double[] V, double[] mp, double[] r, double[] fM) {
    testJNI.compute_feature_set(input, F_data, F_size, D_data, D_size, De_data, De_size, V, mp, r, fM);
  }

  public static void compute_feature_set_terminate() {
    testJNI.compute_feature_set_terminate();
  }

}
```

where `testJNI` is a JNI implementation detail:

```
package com.example.ferasas;

public class testJNI {
  public final static native void compute_feature_set(double[] jarg1, double[] jarg2, int[] jarg3, double[] jarg4, int[] jarg5, double[] jarg6, int[] jarg7, double[] jarg8, double[] jarg9, double[] jarg10, double[] jarg11);
  public final static native void compute_feature_set_terminate();
}
```

You can take a look at `feature_set_wrap.cxx` to see the horrible generated code.

Final note: this copies the arrays from Java to native memory **every time** and should not be used if you expect low-latency results. See [the SWIG manual](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Java.html#Java_unbounded_c_arrays) for a faster but less safe way that avoids copying data.

Alternatively, you can investigate direct `FloatBuffer` and `ByteBuffer` instances, which can be converted to a pointer in native land.